# Issues with running my code in VSC in the integrated terminal due to it opening/creating another folder with the same name

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am a new user to vscode and when I try to run my code in the terminal, it creates/opens up another file with the same name but says "The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding...". However, when I run the code without using the terminal, I see the outputs of my program(C++). As soon as I change back, the code doesn't run.

Comment: How do you run the code in the terminal?

Comment: You go to settings and type in code runner and search for the option.